# My Pearl dragon egg doesn't look like the picture!

Tags: dragonvale

I was breeding the Snow and Seaweed dragons, and got the Pearl egg.  But my egg is blue with a pearl in the middle, not like the picture I saw, where it looks like a pearl.  My question is, why are there two different eggs, and what is the difference, if there is one?

Answer (score 3):

The egg changed.  I speculate that it's in an effort to make all gem eggs similiar.  To quote the [wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Pearl_Dragon):

> The egg for the Pearl Dragon was changed on June 12 from a pale pink egg to a multicolored egg with a pearl in the middle.

The original looked like this:

[image: oldpearl]

The new one looks like this:

[image: newpearl]

Answer (score 0):

I think they're trying to make the egg look more realistic.  Before the egg looked kind of like a cut and paste kind of thing.  But just like firefly and scorch ( I'm not sure if I spelled that right) they change the eggs.  They just want the eggs to look the same and different like they don't want it to look like there will be a series of them where you can breed them etc.